MyGeneration 1303 does not install without MDAC 2.7. Does anyone have it?
I am trying to install MyGeneration 1303 Code Generator on my Windows 11 PC. I need it for an older software that I had developed.
MyGen needs MDAC 2.7. I have been able to download 2.8 but MyGen does not accept it.
Does anyone have the 2.7 version? If yes please mail it to me at:
aakhan314@gmail.com or aakhan@amkfarms.com
Thanks and grateful in advance
I searched all of the web and many forums but to no avail.
